# Launch another app from an activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, transparent

I want to launch a third party app from my android application.
I can do that using `startActivity(intent)`. However, is it possible to start this new intent as transparent?
I know we can start a transparent activity (using `@android:style`).
I started a third party app from this transparent activity but it does not take effect and becomes non-transparent.

Comment: What does "start this new intent ad transparent" mean? Do you mean you are trying to make somebody else's app transparent?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want to make somebody else's app transparent which is opened from my activity.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make somebody else's app transparent which is opened from my activity.

That is not possible. You can make your own UI transparent; you cannot affect the UIs of other apps in that fashion.